# send password through mail if user forgets password in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I use devise for my `web app` and now i change my web app also to respond to `mobile app` and so far for `forgot password` the reset instruction will be sent to the email of the user but now i want the password to be sent to the mail so that the user can check his mail and use the password. But i don't think i can do it because password is `encrypted` in devise so somebody please tell me how to get the password in mail or some other way that i can use for my mobile app. Please help me.

Comment: hopefully you can't. reset the password with one you create or use Devise builtin methods

Comment: then how can i make the forgot password functionality to work. Do i have to follow some other way?

Answer (score 0):

"Forgot password" links usually send the user to a url with a single_access_token hash at the end. There, you identify the user and let them update their password to their liking. This way you do not irritate users who don't want you to have access to their passwords which they might also use for their bank accounts and social connection pages.

Another way is to set the password to a hash such as

```
user.password= @new_pass #MD5.digest(Time.now)[0..7]
# set password_confirmation and reset password token for "change password on login", too, if neccessary
user.save
```

In User model `after_update :email_password_if_password_changed` if password field has changed, you can email their password using activemailer.